# How Does The Babel JS Compiler Convert User Defined Components Syntax (JSX) To Regular Function Calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

> Consider the code below.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const element = <div>Div in Component</div>

function DivComponent() {
  return element
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<DivComponent />, rootElement);
```

**QUESTION 1:**
How does **Babel** know how to convert **`<DivComponent/>`** **JSX** syntax to a regular function invocation **`DivComponent()`** which then returns **`element`** and then the **`div`** HTML tag compiles to...

```
React.createElement("div", null, "Div in Component");
```

which gets rendered in the browser. Does it use **Regular Expressions** or some other technique to replace the JSX syntax?

**QUESTION 2:** 
How does Babel tell the difference between the valid HTML tag **`<div>`** and user-defined tag **`<DivComponent/>`**?

To my understanding, valid HTML tag **`<div>`** get compiled to **`React.createElement("div", null, "Div in Component");`** and then the user defined component tag(JSX) **`<DivComponent/>`** gets compiled to **`DivComponent()`**.

Comment: Q1: By its attributes Q2: By capital letter